# Chef: Reset default values for a recipe

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe, chef-solo

I've 3 recipe

1. my_java
2. my_db_client
3. my_app (depends on my_db_client and my_java)

In my_app I've

default.rb

```
default[:my_app][:user] = "#{node[:my_db_client][:user]}"
default[:my_app][:group] = "#{node[:my_db_client][:group]}"
default[:my_app][:user_home] = "#{node[:my_db_client][:user_home]}"
default[:my_app][:base] = "#{node[:my_db_client][:base]}"
default[:my_app][:oracle_client_home] = "#{node[:my_db_client][:oracle_home]}"
```

In my_db_client I've

default.rb

```
default[:my_db_client][:user] = "" --(Set from Role)
default[:my_db_client][:group] = "" --(Set from Role)
default[:my_db_client][:user_home] = "" --(Set from Role)
default[:my_db_client][:base] = "" --(Set from Role)
default[:my_db_client][:oracle_client_home] = "#{node[:my_db_client][:base]}/oracle/home"
```

Role1

```
default_attributes( 
    :my_db_client => {
        :user => "myuser",
        :group => "mygroup",
        :user_home => '/home',
        :base => '/u01'
    } 
)
run_list( 
    "recipe[my_db_client]",
    "recipe[my_app::_install]"
)
```

Role2

```
default_attributes( 
    :my_java => {
        :user => "myuser",
        :group => "mygroup",
        :user_home => '/home',
        :base => '/u01'
    } 
)
run_list(
    "recipe[my_java]",
    "recipe[my_db_client]",
    "recipe[my_app::_install]"
)
```

For Role1 Things work fine.

But For Role2 the default my_db_client value are set to ""

```
[:my_db_client][:user] = ""
```

1. How can I pass the value from node[:my_java][:user] to
   [:my_db_client][:user] ?
2. How can I also set the below values also ?

   ```
   default[:my_db_client][:oracle_client_home] = "#{node[:my_db_client][:base]}/oracle/home"
   ```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the default value of `node['my_db_client']['user']` to be the value of `node['my_java']['user']` then do that in the attributes file. Not really sure what the question is since you've done that in the other cases already so you must have left it out for some specific reason?

Comment: In my my_app the default.rb values are set from my_db_client nodes, but in role2 I'm capturing the data into my_java node. Now how do I set the values into my_db_client nodes from my_java nodes?

Comment: I don't understand the question, if that's what you want to do, just do it.